# Easiest way to check whether a file abides by some format?

Tags: jena

I've been looking for a simple way to validate whether a file is written in correct syntax (eg. in correct TTL syntax). Is there any simpler way than actually trying to load the model and check for ReadFailure?

Perhaps there would be something similar to this?

```
boolean validateSyntax(File f, Language l) { .... } // returns true if parse result shows syntax validity
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse it but you can parse to a StreamRDF that throws an exception after a some number of triples to avoid parsing the whole file.

For some formats (N-triples vs Turtle) it needs parsing the whole file because N-triples is legal Turtle so have to scan to see if any Turtle-only syntax is used.

In practice, text matching on the start of file is often sufficient.